# Validation metrics stagnate while training keeps improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

This is a model I've been using. It takes a pretrained InceptionV3 model and adds some fully connected layers on top of it. The whole thing is made trainable (including the pretrained InceptionV3 layers).

```py
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    pretrained_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

    x = pretrained_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='gap_final')(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

    preds = Dense(len(config.classes),activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=pretrained_model.input, outputs=preds)

parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=16)
parallel_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I've tried training it with different image augmentation configurations, and no matter what I do the results are always similar to below:

```
Epoch 1/20
181/181 [====] - 1372s 8s/step - loss: 19.2332 - acc: 0.3330 - val_loss: 8.7765 - val_acc: 0.4747
Epoch 2/20
181/181 [====] - 1379s 8s/step - loss: 4.9885 - acc: 0.5474 - val_loss: 3.5256 - val_acc: 0.4084
Epoch 3/20
181/181 [====] - 1354s 7s/step - loss: 2.0334 - acc: 0.6469 - val_loss: 2.5382 - val_acc: 0.4275
Epoch 4/20
181/181 [====] - 1361s 8s/step - loss: 1.3522 - acc: 0.7117 - val_loss: 2.2028 - val_acc: 0.4741
Epoch 5/20
181/181 [====] - 1356s 7s/step - loss: 1.0838 - acc: 0.7599 - val_loss: 2.3402 - val_acc: 0.4738
```

From this point on (epoch 5/20), if I let the model train forever the training loss/acc will keep improving while the validation loss/acc will keep stagnating at these values.

This is a classification problem with 28 different classes, so a validation accuracy of 0.47 is not *that* bad given randomness would give an accuracy of 0.035, however I don't understand how the training set can be so perfectly fitted while the validation set leaves that much to be desired.

The total dataset is made of 32,000 pretty well-labeled images, all in the same configuration (think facial classification problem). Training takes roughly 27,000 and augment them by horizontal flipping and greyscaling (giving a total of 93,000 training images), while validation images are not augmented. From a visual perspective, training and validation images look very similar and I notice no striking difference between these two sets (before augmenting the training set, obviously).

Classes are slightly unbalanced, but not that much: the biggest class has 2,600 images and smallest has 610 (class size distribution is linear between these two extremes).

Note a few things that I've tried and don't alter the results:

- dropouts: little impact if I play around with the dropout rates
- regularization: using L1 or L2 with different values don't change results much
- batch normalisation: with or without, same thing
- number of fully-connected layers: one, two or even three (like above), little difference
- type of pretrained network: I've tried using VGG16 with similar results

No matter what I do, training metrics always improve significantly, while validation stagnates.

Is it only a problem of "getting more data in" with 32,000 images just being "not enough" for 28 classes, especially for currently smaller classes (e.g. the one which has currently 610 images) or am I doing something wrong? Should I use a smaller learning rate, although the one being used currently is already fairly small?

Is it wrong to augment images from the training set and not from the validation set? I've read that it's standard practice, and it also seems to make sense to be doing so...

Lastly, should I limit the layers being trainable? E.g. should I make only the last 10 or 20 layers trainable instead of the full InceptionV3 network? Although choosing the trainable layers is straightforward when using a VGGxx model (being purely sequential), it seems a bit trickier for Inception. Any recommendation regarding this would be welcome.

Comment: I would recommend trying a different regularizer function than L2 or probably try using adam optimizer. And augmenting data from the training set is correct, you should avoid augmenting data from the validation set as it is considered kind of cheating. And one more thing I would recommend is try checking the confusion matrix of the validation set to know what exactly might be happening.

Comment: Thanks @AnuragReddy. I'm already using Adam optimizer, as you can see in the model configuration. What kind of regularizer would you recommend instead of L2? Also, thanks for confirming that augmenting training data only is the right thing to do.

Comment: sorry about asking to add adam optimizer, so in terms of regularization, one configuration is usually the regularizer rate is set to very low value like (0.0005), as few papers have reported good accuracies with that value. But mostly what I would recommend is looking into some techniques like [deep implicit regularization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8306949), [sparse regularization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7966185)

Answer (score 1):

After having tried several models and had a more thorough look at the data, it seems that the labels are not as clear as what I thought, and there is a lot of porosity between the different 28 classes.

Every time the model makes a "wrong" prediction on test data, a careful inspection of the picture makes it apparent that the model was "somehow right" and the labeling was questionable. E.g. think of a face smiling and frowning at the same time. Model could say "happy" or "unhappy" with equal legitimacy, and the "ground truth" labelling would be pretty arbitrary.

So, it seems that 45-ish percent accuracy on the validation set is in the top of what any model (or any human) could get to considering these porous classes.

The ability of InspectionV3 to get to the 85% accuracy for the training set with tens of thousands of images — *after one epoch* — is saying something about its power to find specific patterns that a human couldn't. As this example indicates, this ability must be balanced with equally qualitative regularization.

It also means that given a high-quality dataset with little porosity between labels, InceptionV3 should be able to give good results very quickly, e.g. compared to VGG16.